# Emplacing a std::pair

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

Is there a way of emplacing a `std::pair`?

```
std::unordered_map<int, std::pair<std::string, std::string>> my_map;
my_map.emplace(1, "foo", "bar"); // Error
```

Of course inserting is possible:

```
my_map[2] = std::make_pair("bar", "foo");
```

But doesn't this require unnecessary copying/moving?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> Is there a way of emplacing a std::pair?

The arguments need to be suitable for a constructor of `pair<int, pair<string,string>>`, the map's `value_type`:

```
my_map.emplace(1, std::make_pair("foo", "bar"));
```

> But doesn't this require unnecessary copying/moving?

No; `make_pair` makes a pair of pointers to the string literals, which are then used to initialise (in the case of `emplace`) or assigned to (in the case of `[]`) the strings contained in the map.

Comment: expanding on that - `emplace` doesn't create an object and then move it into the container; it uses *forwarding* to forward the arguments to the container, and then the container invokes the object constructor once the container has figured out where in memory it wants the object constructed.   (Misleading function name!)

Answer (score 24):

In this case there is little point in emplacing the parts of the "value-type" `std::pair`, as `std::string` can both be efficiently converted from a C-string, and can be efficiently moved into the map.  Simple `m.emplace( 3, std::make_pair( "bob", "alice" ) )` and you are 99% of the way to optimal efficiency.

However, if you have a `std::map` that maps to a type that cannot be efficiently constructed that way, C++11 provides `std::piecewise_construct` for `std::pair` to be `emplace`d.

```
struct A { }; // nothing
struct C { C(C&&)=delete; }; // no copy/move
struct B { B()=delete; B(B&&)=delete; B(C&&, C&&) {}; }; // no copy/move, only annoying ctor

std::map< int, std::pair<A,B> > test;
// test.emplace( 0, std::make_pair( A{}, B{} ); // does not compile
// test.emplace( 0, std::make_pair( A{}, B{C{},C{}} ); // does not compile
test.emplace( std::piecewise_construct,
  std::make_tuple(0),
  std::forward_as_tuple(
    std::piecewise_construct,
    std::forward_as_tuple(A{}),
    std::forward_as_tuple( C{}, C{} )
  )
); // compiles!
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/370fdf4b491470ae)

This is an extreme corner case, as efficient-move objects are far more common.

Comment: Er. `std::piecewise_construct` is C++11, not C++14.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is:

```
my_map.emplace(1, std::make_pair("foo", "bar"));
```

Answer (score 1):

With C++17, you can use `try_emplace` for that:

```
std::unordered_map<int, std::pair<std::string, std::string>> my_map;
my_map.try_emplace(1, "foo", "bar");
```